# Performance with a lot of graphics on smartphones

Tags: android, graphics, smartphone

I'm looking for some advice regarding recent smartphones, Im working on android, so if anyone
has specific info regarding that platform it would be appreciated.

Im about to start work on a particluar section of my app which may require a lot of images on screen,
possibly 30 at once. Potentially I could put in some heavy processing and reduce this.

I've not really had a chance to work on a lot of mobiles, and I understand they ovbiously vary wildly, so I was hoping if anyone has had experience in testing graphics like this, what would be the best method in terms of performance.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the question? I'm voting to close as it is too vague. I'd suggest trying  to write your app then come back here with a specific question if you met a performance bottleneck and need help to improve it.

Comment: @Lie Ryan : Choosing the right technology from the ground up makes more sense to me than having to rewrite everything because it was a bad idea to use standard android layouts.

Comment: Thanks calvin, I'll look into the methods

Comment: @Calvin1602,@user723789: my recommendation, as always in these kind of situations, is to write a prototype with the technology you're most familiar with first or, if you're not familiar with any, the technology that you think is most inclined for rapid development. In many cases you'd find that it is fast enough, and in cases where you found that the technology you used is not fast enough then you would spend the least amount of time prototyping and would have learned about issues that would make it easier to write the final implementation. Don't be afraid to throw away codes.

Answer (score 0):

Well OpenGLES will give you the best performance. However it may be complete overkill depending on how large the images are, what format and how much they move.

Comment: Well, then my advice is to look at the android home screen and app drawer, they have 30+ small images and if the performance of that is adequate for your use case, then you should just use the default android layout apis.